# Finding area of region enclosed by several curves in the first quadrant

Tags: multivariable-calculus, area, curves

> Find the area of the region in the first quadrant enclosed by the curves $$ xy = 4, xy = 10, y = e^4x, y = e^9x $$

Im aware i have to do a substitution, but Im not sure how to go about finding a good one.

Comment: have you made an Image?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I graphed the functions in Geogebra so i have an idea of that the region looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: you can do a change of variable adapted to the figure. With
$$u = xy,\qquad v = y/x,$$
the integration limits in the new variables are constant and the jacobian is...

EDIT: about the jacobian:
$$u/v = x^2\implies x =\sqrt{u/v},$$
$$uv = y^2\implies y =\sqrt{uv},$$
$$\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)} = \cdots$$
Alternative possibility:
$$
\frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(x,y)} =
\left|\matrix{y&x\cr -y/x^2& 1/x}\right| = 2y/x = 2v
$$
and
$$\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)} = \frac1{\frac{\partial(u,v)}{\partial(x,y)}} =\frac1{2v}.$$

Comment: Okay so i get the answer $$6u(e^9 - e^4) $$ I got this just by multiplying the sides of the rectangle. But they want a number as the answer. I got that the jacobian is $u$.

Comment: Should i set up an integral somehow? Isn't the are just the area of the rectangle in the uv plane?

Comment: @Pame, *isn't*. The jacobian is required (*can* be $1$, of course).

Comment: But if you multiply the area of the rectangle by the jacobian you get $$6u(e^9−e^4)$$ also they want a rational number for the answer.

Comment: @Pame, the area of the region is the *integral* of the jacobian in the *new* variables: $\iint(1/2v)dudv$.

Comment: Ok so $\frac{1}{2v}$ is correct. But if you compute $$\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)} = \left|\matrix{\frac1y&0\cr 0& x}\right| = \frac xy = \frac1v $$ Just from using $u = xy$ and $v = \frac yx$

Comment: @Pame, *doubly wrong*. In $\partial(x,y)/\partial(u,v)$ you have the partial derivatives of $x,y$ with respect  $u,v$ and your $\partial_y u$, $\partial_x v$ are incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

In polar coordinates we seek to find the area between$$r=\dfrac{\sqrt{10}}{\sqrt{\sin\theta\cos\theta}}\\r=\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{\sin\theta\cos\theta}}\\\theta=\tan^{-1}e^4\\\theta=\tan^{-1}e^9$$so we have$$S=\int_{\tan^{-1}e^4}^{\tan^{-1}e^9}\int_{\frac{\sqrt{10}}{\sqrt{\sin\theta\cos\theta}}}^{\frac{2}{\sqrt{\sin\theta\cos\theta}}}rdrd\theta=\int_{\tan^{-1}e^4}^{\tan^{-1}e^9}\dfrac{3}{\sin\theta\cos\theta}d\theta$$